# How to draw Rectangle with arrow in java?

Tags: java, swing

How I can draw rectangle with arrow with paint event in java JApplet :)

Something like FaceBook message:

[image]

Comment: If you found a solution then post your working code I would be interested to see how you achieved the custom painting.

Comment: Look up **9-patch image**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying using polygon and rectangle.

I keep forgetting about using the `Area` class when playing with `Shape` objects.

You can just use the `add(...)` method to add two Shapes together and then paint them:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BalloonRectangle extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 150, 50);

        Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
        triangle.addPoint(0, 0);
        triangle.addPoint(10, 5);
        triangle.addPoint(0, 10);
        triangle.translate(150, 10);

        Area balloon = new Area( rectangle );
        balloon.add( new Area( triangle ) );

        g2d.translate(50, 50);
        g2d.setColor( Color.YELLOW );
        g2d.fill( balloon );
        g2d.setColor( Color.GRAY );
        g2d.draw( balloon );

        g2d.dispose();
     }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BalloonRectangle");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new BalloonRectangle() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setSize(250, 200);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can also check out [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for more ideas.

Comment: Why need use g2.dispose()? i don't get difference. I get result same without g2.dispose().

Comment: @user3420235, it is good practice to release the Graphic resource when you create your own Graphics object. Of course you should never use dispose on the Graphics object passed into the painting method.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see your image, but if you want to draw a combination of geometric primitives, then you can either use Shapes such as Rectangle2D and Polygon, and fill these using a Graphics2D instance. Don't draw directly in a JApplet's paint method but rather in a JPanel's paintComponent method that the applet displays.

Comment: I will try to use shapes :) maybe someone will know what exactly need to use :) I'm trying using polygon and rectangle.

Comment: @user3420235: good, give them a try, and if still stuck, come back with your code

Comment: Maybe someone can give example how need to do? :) becouse i'm  trying like this: http://pastebin.com/xJ1q1g1X MPanel, here i creating My panel with rounded corners :)